# Check box list limit selection and get clicked value

Tags: jquery, asp.net

How to Check whether the check box box list selection limited to 2 and get the last selected value. I have one check box list in my asp.net page. So while the user clicks on more than one check box from that particular list i have to display an alert message. Also i have to identify the check box value.

If any one go through a problem like this please help me

thanks in advance.

I have find the solution.

`$(document).ready(function () {
            $("[id*=chkOptions] input:checkbox").change(function () {
                var maxSelection = 2;
                if ($("[id*=chkOptions] input:checkbox:checked").length > maxSelection) {
                    $(this).prop("checked", false);
                    alert("Please select a maximum of " + maxSelection + " options.");
                    //to get the value
            $(this).val();
        }
            });
        });`

Comment: Atleast formulate question properly.

Comment: you can do it with jquery

Comment: you need a counter to control if the clicked checkbox should be checked or not.

Comment: Please remove the hold status

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
   $('input:checkbox').on('change', function(evt) {
   if($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= 2) {
       this.checked = false;
       console.log(this.value)
   }
   });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vVxM2/89/)

Answer (score 1):

```
function checkCheckboxCount()
{
    var checkedValues = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked");

    if(checkedValues.length==2)
    {
        console.log('Number of checkbox selected are 2');
        console.log('Last value:'+checkedValues[1]);
        return checkedValues[1];
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Use this function on event you want to check the number of checkbox elements clicked and get the second of two values if two are clicked.